How to give tolerance value in robot framework
In robotframework I am comparing 2 values
*** Settings ***
Library    BuiltIn

*** Test Cases ***
Compare Values With Tolerance
  ${value1}    Set Variable    0.61
  ${value2}    Set Variable    0.62
  Should Be Equal As Numbers    ${value1}    ${value2}    tolerance=0.01

But the above keyword still getting failed even though the difference is 0.01. How can I resolve this?
Used 
Should Be Equal As Numbers    ${value1}    ${value2}    tolerance=0.01

Expected: Test case should pass as the difference is 0.01 which is same as tolerance value

there's no such argument as tolerance for  Should Be Equal As Numbers, however, there's precision: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20Equal%20As%20Numbers

As mentioned in the comment, Should Be Equal As Numbers only has precision option but it indicates how many decimals are considered so its not same as precision.
You use use something like (abs(x-y)>precision) to get a failure if x and y are not within given tolerance.
Should Be Equal Within Given Tolerance
  [Documentation]    Compares two values and fails if the difference is greater than the given tolerance.
  ...
  ...   Args:
  ...      ${val1}: First numeric value
  ...      ${val2}: Second numeric value
  ...      ${tolerance}:  tolerance
  ...      ${decimalprecision}:  decimal precision for rounding the difference. Default is 5.
  [Arguments]   ${val1}   ${val2}   ${tolerance}   ${decimalprecision}=5
  ${diff}=   Evaluate   round(abs(${val1}-${val2}), ${decimalprecision})

  IF   ${diff} > ${tolerance}
    Fail   Values ${val1} and ${val2} are not equal within given tolerance ${tolerance}, Difference: ${diff}
  END


As mentioned, Should Be Equal As Numbers does not support a tolerance argument. I have two options for you to handle it. In both options, if the difference between ${value1} and ${value2} is greater than the tolerance, the test case fails. Otherwise, it is passed.

Using a custom keyword

For example:
*** Keywords ***
Should Be Equal With Tolerance
    [Arguments]    ${value1}    ${value2}    ${tolerance}
    ${difference}=    Evaluate    round(abs(${value1} - ${value2}),10)
    Run Keyword If    ${difference} > ${tolerance}    Fail    ${value1} and ${value2} differ by ${difference}, which is greater than the tolerance of ${tolerance}

*** Test Cases ***
Compare Values With Tolerance
    ${value1}    Set Variable    0.61
    ${value2}    Set Variable    0.62
    Should Be Equal With Tolerance    ${value1}    ${value2}    0.01


Using Run Keyword If

For example:
*** Test Cases ***
Compare Values With Tolerance
    ${value1}   Set Variable    0.61
    ${value2}   Set Variable    0.62
    ${tolerance}    Set Variable    0.01
    ${difference}=    Evaluate    round(abs(${value1} - ${value2}),10)
    Run Keyword If    ${difference} > ${tolerance}    Fail    ${value1} and ${value2} differ by ${difference}, which is greater than the tolerance of ${tolerance}

